# Need help understanding jquery syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For this segment of code:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
         var imageCrystal = $('<img>');
         imageCrystal.attr('data-num', numbers[i]);
         ....
    }
```

is, `imageCrystal.attr('data-num', numbers[i]);` making a data attribute for the image tag that was just created and giving it a class name called `"data-num"` and then assigning whatever the value is at `number[i]`?

Comment: attr creates an attribute in the element. Attributes prefixed with `data-` are an HTML5 thing for storing data in the element. So if `numbers[i]` was 3, this would make an `imageCrystal` element that looks like `<img data-num="3" />`. Data attributes can also be accessed using the jQuery `data` function, so `imageCrystal.data("num")` should return 3.

Comment: Worth noting here that the last line can be written as `imageCrystal.data('num', numbers[i]);` also if you use the [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method.

Comment: @DavidG haha, just added my edit right as you posted that.

Comment: ahh I got it. Thank you for the clarification. I am new to jquery and it is totally different from c++ syntax. Is there a place where I can look up jquery attributes like 'data'? For example, I didnt even know the data() function could be set in the html tags directyl using the jquery atrribute.

Comment: isnt that creating a new img element? Also, I have an click function after this where $('.crystalImage').on(
    'click', function() {
     counter = counter + parseInt($(this).data('woohoo'));

Comment: No, `$("xxx")` is saying "get me all elements that match xxx". With jQuery syntax for example, you can say `img` which is all img elements or `.class` which is all elements with a particular class.

Comment: i thought that was making a new image element and not a selector

Comment: @DavidG: The `.data()` method doesn't make a `data-` attribute. It just stores the data in jQuery's cache. This is often unnecessary and sometimes people want or need the data directly on the element.

Comment: @henhen: You're correct. That `$("<img>")` syntax makes a new element. And the `data-num` attribute is a distinct concept from jQuery's own `.data()` store, which is usually not needed.

Comment: Would it be possible to add more than one data value this way? For example do something like var a = 3; var b = 4; imageCrystal.attr('data-num', numbers[i], a, b);???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply put

`imageCrystal.attr('data-num', numbers[i]);` is a **setter**

`imageCrystal.attr('data-num');` is a **getter**

If `var numbers = [100, 200, 300]` and if the `img` tags are appended to the `DOM`, it would look something in these lines.

```
<img data-num="100" />
<img data-num="200" />
<img data-num="300" />
```

More info: http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: thank you for the clarification also. I am new to jquery and am still trying to understand the syntax of jquery.